# Meteor.js way to show markdown from another link

Tags: meteor, markdown

I have a README.md file in github repository. I want to show contents of README.md file in my website as well. But I don't want to copy contents of README.md file and place it inside markdown file as below.

```
{{#markdown}}
   //copy of README.md file
{{/markdown}}
```

Is there way to do something line this.

```
{{#markdown}}
   //link to existing markdown file on github.
{{/markdown}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this example:

http://meteorpad.com/pad/29fYNyFxBPWKstBSH/GitHub%20md%20read%20example

If it is not loading try to refresh or go to the link showed in the console, after app start.

Remember that you need HTTP package and your own GitHub API credentials.